# Notification listeners causing crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using the following code to detect/listen for when the iPad changes device orientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                               object:nil];
```

This calls my didRotate: method when something changes. In my didRotate: method, I use `UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];` to figure out what the orientation is, and apply my code accordingly.

However, in real life testing, I noticed that didRotate: gets called every second if the iPad is in a person's hand. It appears the listener is literally listening for every little tilt and shift in the iPad, which obviously happens a lot in a person's hands (as opposed to flat on a desk).

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I could change my code to use interface orientations, but I've been having trouble with it for whatever reason. Thank you.

***UPDATE**: This listener is created in my UIImageView subclass. There are about a dozen or more on the screen. I have added `[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` to my removal methods for when I remove an instance. That helps explain why didRotate kept showing up so much (my error).

However, I have narrowed down crashes: whenever I remove this an instance of this subclass, and rotate my iPad, I crash. Sometimes I get weird messages like [__NSArrayM didRotate]: is unrecognized selector (and other wierd objects like UIPanVelocity...something). Is my listener still listening after the instance is removed?

**FIXED**: Thank you for your help. I finally noticed what was wrong. I was removing the instance without removing the observer and ending notifications. Adding following code into my instance removal methods fixes my problem:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: As a side note, use the constant `name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` not its string value `name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you add observers repeatedly and never remove them.  This means that the same entry point may get invoked multiple times for a single event.  It also means that when the "self" object goes away you get a crash.

Answer (score 1):

The notification is only sent if the device changes from one orientation to another orientation - it doesn't get fired more times than necessary.

`UIDeviceOrientation` has 2 more orientations than `UIInterfaceOrientation`. It has FaceUp and FaceDown.  Possibly it is these that are getting triggered, and you're not interested in them.

```
typedef enum {
UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

Maybe you would prefer to listen for UIInterfaceOrientation changes in the view controller that is currently onscreen.

```
typedef enum {
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: Hi there, I have an NSLog in my didRotate method and its showing that its constantly being called. The only method calling didRotate is the device orientation listener I mentioned earlier, so I'm 100% sure the listener keeps calling my didRotate. If I lay my iPad flat on my desk, it is not called. When it is in my hands and moving around but not even rotating, didRotate is being called. Thanks

Comment: Where did you add the code you posted? Maybe that bit of code is called multiple times - cumulating lots of observers, hence didRotate: gets called multiple times - once for each observer added, albeit the same observer.

Comment: Hi there, this is correct. This listener goes into every UIImageView which I show on the screen (up to about a dozen or more). I'm narrowing crashes to this. I've added [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; to my removal methods. It looks like whenever an imageview is removed, and I moved the iPad, it crashes.